# How to desearilize Json and bind to variables/properties c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var AdditionalData = flexEventTriggerLogsList.Select(x => x.AdditionalData).ToString();
            string json = Convert.ToString(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(AdditionalData));
            var objTriggerLog = new FlexEventTriggerLog();
            objTriggerLog.lookupEntity_RecordId = ????
            objTriggerLog.DocumentRecordIds = ????
```

Additinal data wil return my Json object in string. I have to use that object to get my entity and document record ids.

Json object which will be returned:

```
{
    "lookupEntity_RecordId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "DocumentRecordIds":["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]
    }
```

Comment: Question already have the code you are asking for - `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(AdditionalData)`... could you please clarify what exactly you need help with?

Comment: I want to bind the deserialized object to my c# class object properties .i.e. lookupEntity_RecordId and DocumentRecordIds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring)`

You create a model for your json

```
public class AdditionalDataModel
{
    public string lookupEntity_RecordId { get; set; }
    public List<string> DocumentRecordIds { get; set; }
}
```

then deserialize your json in model

```
var AdditionalData = flexEventTriggerLogsList.Select(x => x.AdditionalData).ToString();
var additionalDataModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdditionalDataModel>(AdditionalData);
var objTriggerLog = new FlexEventTriggerLog();`
objTriggerLog.lookupEntity_RecordId = additionalDataModel.lookupEntity_RecordId;
objTriggerLog.DocumentRecordIds = additionalDataModel.DocumentRecordIds;
```